# Create or replace global subtype

Tags: oracle, plsql, subtype

I know that I can create a subtype inside a package specification like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XY
AS
  SUBTYPE type_sdebug IS VARCHAR (200);
  ...
END;
/
```

If I want to use the same subtype within another package then I need to redefine the same type again. Is there a way to create or replace a global subtype such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS VARRAY(500) OF VARCHAR2(30);
/
```

Comment: Did you even try to create your "global" type? If you had, you would have seen that it is totally possible.

Comment: @Boneist IMHO you misread the question. The OP wants to create a global *SUBTYPE* (not a global *TYPE). AFAIK, this is not possible.

Comment: Ah, indeed I did! D'oh. Need more caffeine! Apologies, My-Name-Is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, SUBTYPEs are a PL/SQL feature, so you cannot create them globally. But nothing prevents you from using a type defined in your package `XY` in another package (e.g. `AB`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XY
AS
  SUBTYPE type_sdebug IS VARCHAR (200);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE AB
AS
  PROCEDURE print_it(p_Debug in XY.type_sdebug);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY AB
AS
  PROCEDURE print_it(p_Debug in XY.type_sdebug) is
  begin
      dbms_output.put_line(p_Debug);
  end;
END;


declare
  v_Debug XY.type_sdebug default 'hello world';
begin
  ab.print_it(v_Debug);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've read the question correctly *{;-) , according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#i2126475) you can indeed create a subtype:

*"This statement shows how the subtype corporate_customer_typ in the sample oe schema was created. It is based on the customer_typ supertype created in the preceding example and adds the account_mgr_id attribute. A hypothetical name is given to the table so that you can duplicate this example in your test database:"*

```
CREATE TYPE corporate_customer_typ_demo UNDER customer_typ
    ( account_mgr_id     NUMBER(6)
    );
```

You may need additional privileges to be able to do so though, according to the [prerequisites for creating types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#BABCHABE):

*"To create a subtype, you must have the UNDER ANY TYPE system privilege or the UNDER object privilege on the supertype."*